# Error: failed to normalize chaincode path: 'go list' failed with: Use -buildvcs=false to disable VCS stamping.: exit status 1

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, amazon-managed-blockchain

I am follownig this tutorial - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/hyperledger-fabric-dev/get-started-chaincode.html - when i am using this command - `docker exec cli peer lifecycle chaincode package ./abstore.tar.gz --path fabric-samples/chaincode/abstore/go/ --label abstore_1`, this give me following error -
`Error: failed to normalize chaincode path: 'go list' failed with: error obtaining VCS status: exit status 128 Use -buildvcs=false to disable VCS stamping.: exit status 1`.
Expected result - it should create abstore.tar.gz file of chaincode.
I am using go version go1.18.4

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on this issue? For example, your version of GoLang, your ~/.bash_profile, etc.? The answer below marking `--lang go` in your chaincode package command is also good to add for the sake of best practice.

Comment: i have also tried `--lang go`  But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

this issue occurs when git is not configured properly.

Answer (score -1):

could you try to add --lang go